# What Islam says about bride’s presence and public consent during nikah? Is that not mandatory?

Tags: nikah

Nobody usually care about a bride’s presence or consent during nikah.almost all nikahs in our place takes place without the bride.is it valid and why?

Comment: The marriage of Fatimah thd daughter of the prophet has been fixed in her absence.